# How to add to a value in a LinkedList

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to add to a shopping cart items.  If the item exists then I need to update the quantity (amount) of the item by calling a method.  I get it to work by adding items, but when I implement the part where it needs to update the existing item, it doesn't function any longer.  Please check out the add method and nudge me in the right direction.  Thanks!!!

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ShoppingBasket {

    private List<Purchase> basket;

    public ShoppingBasket() {
        basket = new LinkedList<Purchase>();
    }

    public void add(String product, int price) {

        for (Purchase item : basket) { // cycle through the list

            if (item.getProduct().equals(product)) { // item exists, update qty
                item.increaseAmount();
            } else { //item does not exist so add it to the list
                basket.add(new Purchase(product, 1, price));
            }
        }
    }

    public int price() {
        int price = 0;
        for (Purchase item : basket) {
            price += item.price();
        }
        return price;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (Purchase item : basket) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}





public class Purchase {
    private String product;
    private int amount;
    private int unitPrice;

    public Purchase(String product, int amount, int unitPrice) {
        this.product = product;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;

    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }


    public int price() {
        // which returns the purchase price. This is obtained by raising the unit amount by the unit price

        return this.amount * this.unitPrice;
    }

    public void increaseAmount() {
        // increases by one the purchase unit amount
        this.amount++;
    }

    public String toString() {
        //returns the purchase in a string form like the following
        return this.product + ": " + amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe _it doesn't function any longer._.

Comment: It doesn't actually add the item or update. The entire method seems to just stop working.

Comment: Does it throw an exception ! If it does not whoever flagged it as duplicate was just wrong

Comment: Yea, it is throwing: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException now.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis try to understand the code first -.-. the concurrentmodificationexception is only the tip of the iceberg

Comment: @Paul We're not debuggers. OP doesn't provide more than _it doesn't function any longer_ and latter _it is throwing ConcurrentModificationException_. This is not an example of a good or useful question. It doesn't help the community. The implicit purpose of putting a question on hold is to have the OP update it with all relevant details. We don't want people answering with random assumptions. Vote to re-open at your leisure, but I doubt this question, in its current state, brings any benefit to the community.

Comment: @SotoriosDelimanolos actually it might help the community since it's a perfect example for how querying a dataset shouldn't be done. And as the current accepted answer shows this is a quite important topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might because your add method does not consider the case where the basket is actually empty first. I might be wrong since I'm on my phone and it's hard to test the code but I suggest adding something like:

```
If(basket.size()==0) basket.add(new Purchase(product, price));
```

Edit: 
The exception you now get after adding my piece of code get is due to the fact that you are actually modifying the list and going through it at the same time. This is not allowed (whether for removing or adding elements to the list)

The solution is then to iterate over your list until you find the position where you should add the new item or modify the amount with a while loop, once you're done with that you can simply use the index to add at the end or to modify the amount. 
Since I'm on my phone I won't use your variables names and all but it would be something like this ( disclaimer not tested )

```
int k=0 ;
bool found=false ;
while(k<list.size() && found==false){
    if(objectToAdd.equals(list.get(k)) found = true 
    k++
}
if(k==list.size()) list.add(objectToAdd) 
else list.get(k-1).amount ++ ;
```

Comment: Tried that, but it throws an exception when I'm trying to modify the list. ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: In that case the answer is definitely in the post suggested when your question was flagged as duplicate. Edit on the way to help you more

Comment: I see, I can't modify while iterating through the list.  Thanks!

Comment: Hope my edit will help ! However I would advise trying to understand list better first as you seem to make a lot of mistakes when it comes to handling just the add function.

Comment: This is actually the first time using a list.  Trying to learn them as we speak so thanks for the mini tutorial there, much appreciated.

Comment: Sure no worries. I would suggest going through some tutorials on data types first to learn about stacks, queues, lists ... I remembered I learned them all with algorithm on paper first in college and then in c on my computer back home. You should do the same ! Helped me a lot ! Thanks for the upvote and the answer accepted. Good luck